# Bindings seems broken while using observable collection

Tags: wpf, binding, observablecollection

I have a ViewModel with an Observable Collection Property

```
 public ObservableCollection<GeographicArea> CurrentSensorAreasList
 {
     get
     {
        return currentSensorAreasList;
     }
     set
     {
        if (currentSensorAreasList != value)
        {
            currentSensorAreasList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(PROPERTY_NAME_CURRENT_SENSOR_AREAS_LIST);
         }
      }
  }
```

Then in my xaml i have a binding

> ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentSensorAreasList}">

This Observable Collection is updated trought a method that can be call in the viewModel constructor or when a collectionchanged handler from another list gets called.

I just clear the list and then add a fewer new items. While debugging i see all my new items updated on the list. But the UI does not get updated. 
When i regenerate the viewModel and then this update method gets call in the constructor the list gets updated in the UI.

Any ideas?? I don't know if the problem comes when i call the method from a handler.....

**UPDATE #1**

As requested i'm going the code when I update the list
I have tested two ways to do this update

```
    private void UpdateList1()
        {
            if (globalAreaManagerList != null && OperationEntity != null) 
            {

              CurrentSensorAreasList.Clear();                         
              CurrentSensorAreasList.AddRange(globalAreaManagerList.Where(x => x != (OperationEntity as AreaManager)).SelectMany(areaRenderer => areaRenderer.AreaList));
```

//AddRange is an extension method.

```
            }
        }
private void UpdateList2()
        {
            if (globalAreaManagerList != null && OperationEntity != null) 
            {
                CurrentSensorAreasList = new ObservableCollection<GeographicArea>(globalAreaManagerList.Where(x => x != (OperationEntity as AreaManager)).SelectMany(areaRenderer => areaRenderer.AreaList))


            }
        }
```

Both cases works when i call it from the constructor. Then I have Other Lists where the Areas changes, and i get notified via CollectionChanged Handlers.

```
private void globalAreaManagerList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (AreaManager newItem in e.NewItems)
                {
                    newItem.AreaList.CollectionChanged += AreaList_CollectionChanged;
                }
            }
            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (AreaManager oldItem in e.OldItems)
                {
                    oldItem.AreaList.CollectionChanged -= AreaList_CollectionChanged;
                }
            }
            UpdateList();
        }
        private void AreaList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateList();
        }
```

So when i use UpdateList1 seems to work more times but suddenly the Binding is broken and then this update does not show in the UI.

Comment: That looks all ok. Please show the code where you are updating the collection.

Comment: I put the code where i update the list. it seems strange because sometimes works and others not...

Answer (score 0):

If you wish change exactly an instance of collection I recomend using `DependecyProperty` for that case.

Here is:

```
    public ObservableCollection<GeographicArea> CurrentSensorAreasList
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<GeographicArea>)GetValue(CurrentSensorAreasListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentSensorAreasListProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentSensorAreasListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentSensorAreasList", typeof(ObservableCollection<GeographicArea>), typeof(ownerclass));
```

Where `ownerclass` - a name of class where you put this property.

But the better way is create only one instance of `ObservaleCollection` and then just change its items. I mean `Add`, `Remove`, and `Clear` methods.